# Deve declarar um corpo porque não está marcado como abstract, extern ou partial

Tags: c#, visual-studio, classes

Sou novo em programação e estou tentando usar a Classe ***SendKeys*** seguindo este  [link](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.sendkeys.send?view=netframework-4.7.2), porem ao colocar o:

```
public static void Send(string keys);
```

o compilador me retorna o seguinte erro: 
*Erro   **CS0501**  "Teclas.Send(string)" deve declarar um corpo porque não está marcado como ***abstract***, ***extern*** ou ***partial***.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você está tentando implementar a classe [`SendKeys`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.sendkeys.send?view=netframework-4.7.2)? Não faça isso!

`SendKeys` é uma classe que provém métodos para enviar um pressionar de teclas para o aplicativo.

Quando precisar usar da funcionalidade dessa classe em seu código basta fazer:

```
SendKeys.Send(/*Aqui vai a tecla que deseja enviar*/);
```

Cada tecla é representado por um ou mais caracteres. Para especificar um caractere de teclado única, use o próprio caractere. Por exemplo, para representar a letra A, passe a string "A" para o método. Para representar mais de um caractere, acrescente cada caractere adicional para aquele que precede. Para representar as letras A, B e C, especifique o parâmetro como "ABC".

O sinal de adição (+), circunflexo (^), sinal de porcentagem (%), til (~) e parênteses () possuem significados especiais para SendKeys. Para especificar um desses caracteres, coloque-o entre chaves ({}). Por exemplo, para especificar o sinal de adição, use "{+}". Para especificar caracteres de chave, use "{{}"e"{}}". Colchetes ([]) não têm significado especial para SendKeys, mas você deve incluí-los entre chaves. Em outros aplicativos, os colchetes têm um significado especial que pode ser significativo quando ocorre a troca dinâmica de dados (DDE).

Comment: Tentei fazer assim mais cedo porem não estava dando "SendKeys não existe no contexto atual".
Segue imagem do erro: https://imgur.com/a/2f0My0H

Comment: Tem essa clausula `using System.Windows.Forms;` no seu programa?

Comment: Era isso mesmo, acabei nem percebendo. Muito Obrigado.  :)